# ASP.NET MVC 3 project in Xamarin gives System.UnauthorizedAccessException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, xamarin

I run Xamarin (4.0.10 build 5) on Mac OS X (10.9). I created ASP.NET MVC 3 project. First run gave error with Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages. I solved this issue following [this](http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2013/Jun-24.html) article and fixed it. Now when I run it gives another error:

> **System.UnauthorizedAccessException** Access to the path "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.0/etc/mono/registry"
>   is denied.
>
> Stack trace:
>
> at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path)
>   [0x00064] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:113    at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x000a4]
>   in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:80
>   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/DirectoryInfo.cs:141
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo:Create
>   ()   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String
>   path) [0x00039] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:98
>   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x000a4]
>   in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:80
>   at Microsoft.Win32.KeyHandler..ctor (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey,
>   System.String basedir, Boolean is_volatile) [0x0004a] in
>   /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin-no-pcl/build-root/mono-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/Microsoft.Win32/UnixRegistryApi.cs:136

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if [this blog post](http://curtis.schlak.com/2013/09/29/setup-asp-net-mvc-4-on-monodevelop.html) helps you.

(a crack at a solution)

```
sudo mkdir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/etc/mono/registry
sudo chmod g+rwx /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/etc/mono/registry
```

Comment: As I noticed it crash for most of users of Xamarin. It is shame to pay almost 300 $ for soft studio which crash app at first start :(

Comment: @KenanBek If it makes you feel better, the MVC 3 portion of Xamarin Studio is free. They charge you to build for mobile.

Answer (score 4):

On a Linux machine running Arch distribution I made the following changes to make the security issue work:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/mono/registry
sudo mkdir /etc/mono/registry/LocalMachine
sudo chmod g+rwx /etc/mono/registry/
sudo chmod g+rwx /etc/mono/registry/LocalMachine
```